# How can I install Google API client library on server for php without Shell (SSH) access?

Tags: php, git, shell, ftp, google-api-php-client

I'm with HostPapa and they don't allow Shell access, only FTP.  How can I install Google's API client library on my server?  I'm a noob with git as well.  I was trying to follow this guide...

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation

but I either need Composer or Shell access.  Is there another way?  Thanks so much.

edit:  trying something.  I uploaded the library to my working directory.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/google-api-php-client-1.1.7/src');
require 'Google/autoload.php';
require 'Google/Client.php';
// my code...
```

when I try to run my php script I get

```
<b>Warning</b>:  require(Google/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/path/to/my/script.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
   <br />
   <b>Warning</b>:  require(Google/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/path/to/my/script.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
   <br />
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  require(): Failed opening required 'Google/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/google-api-php-client-1.1.7/src') in <b>/path/to/my/script.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
```

edit:  K, I messed up.. should be...

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'google-api-php-client-1.1.7/src');
require 'Google/autoload.php';
require 'Google/Client.php';
// my code...
```

I had to take out the '/' at the beginning of my relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the released version from: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases
2. Set include path: set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'your/path/to/src');
3. Now include autoloader file: require 'Google/autoload.php';
4. Your tasks: 
   require 'Google/Client.php'; // your stuff

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying your solution.  Can you see my edit above?  Does it look right?  Is there an easy way to test if it is working?

Comment: It woked.  At first instead of 'your/path/to/src' I put '/your/path/to/src'.  Woops.  Your solution was the simplest.